# What happened when importing?

Tags: python

I try to handle circular import, code as follows

logs.py

```py
from settings import setting

def _print():
    if setting.is_print:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

setttings.py

```py
from logs import _print


class Setting:
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_print = True

    @staticmethod
    def print_exception():
        return _print()


setting = Setting()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setting.print_exception()
```

When I execute settings.py, output as below

```py
ImportError: cannot import name '_print'
```

I tried changing file  `settings.py` as follow

```py
try:
    from logs import _print
except ImportError:
    pass

class Setting:
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_print = True

    @staticmethod
    def print_exception():
        return _print()


setting = Setting()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setting.print_exception()
```

Output when running after changing `setting.py`

```py
yes
```

I don't know what it happened

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    from logs import _print
except ImportError:
    pass
```

this block is making sure there is no import loop, so the code execute normally.